# How to move data from cell A to cell B if conditioned are met and delete the data from cell A in process

Tags: excel, powershell

So I am new to Powershell and, well, coding. What I am trying to do is that I have an excel where I focus on two columns. Column A consists of numbers [IDs]. Problem is, sometimes there are more numbers separated by a comma. What I want to do is find such instances, split and pick the last number. That last number then move to column B into the corresponding row. And of course, delete the moved number from column A from that row.

```
Column A    Column B
55, 41, 35
15, 23
41
```

So far I have managed to come up with a way how to loop through column A, find such instances and split them. But I have problems figuring how to move the data to column B and delete them from column A [not whole row in column A but only the moved numbers, e.g. in row [1] consist of 55, 41, 35 I would move 35to the corresponding row in column B and delete the 35 from the row in column A.

And unfortunately, I cannot install PowerShell plugin for excel sheets.

```bsh
$path = "D:\User\Documents\Workspace\Book2.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Sheet1")

# Select data in column3 without header.
$column3 = $WorkSheet.Columns.Item(3).value2
$column4 = $WorkSheet.Columns.Item(4).value2

# Loop to find the rows with multiple numbers [IDs] and split
$End = foreach ($line in $column3) {
  if ($line -like "*,*") {
    $line.Split(" ") | Select-Object -Last 1
  }
}
```

After reading some posts here and on Spiceworks I tried to modify the loop so it moves the data from the column A to column B. But unsuccessfully.

```bsh
foreach ($line in $column3) {
  $column4 = $line | ? { $_.ID -eq $line.ID }
  if ($line -like "*,*") {
    $line.Split(" ") | Select-Object -Last 1
    $line.Update()
  }
}
```